# Conditional format a blank cell based on another cells date

Tags: excel, date, format, conditional-statements

First thank you and sorry as I am very new at this.

I need to have a cell come up red if blank, based on another cells entered date plus "X" number of days.

Example:
If A2 shows 2/1/16 and B2 is blank (greater than 2 days from A2) I need it to come up red. So if today's date is 2/5/16 this cell would become red.

If A2 shows 2/1/16 and B3 is blank (by greater than 4 days from A2's date) I need it to come up red.

If a cell is blank and it is not greater than the number of days I set, it remains unchanged. (A2 shows 2/1/16 and today is 2/2/16, B2 would remain blank) Also if a date is entered and it is greater than the number of days I set as compared to A2 it would also come up red. (A2 is 2/1/16 and B2 shows 2/5/16)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is that Excel? If so you should add the tag to your question. Have you tried to use Conditional Formatting > Manage rules > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format?

Comment: Corrected tag, thanks! I was there exactly, but I don't know how to tell it the selected cell (which has the date in it) and then tell it to add a number of specific days past that date before coloring the blank cell red..

Comment: Select the cell you want to colour, go to the formula conditional formatting and In the formula add something like `=TODAY()-A2<3` and choose the formatting you want.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I just had to switch one thing. =TODAY()-A2>3  Worked perfect! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted by @assylias in the comments and the author said it was the solution. I slightly formatted the steps so they are easier to follow.

1. Select the cell you want to colour
2. Go to conditional formatting
3. In the formula add something like `=TODAY()-A2<3` and choose the formatting you want.